Moderated Mediation in a "Two-Step" Structural Equation Model
Can someone please help me figure out how to include a moderator in the structural equation model (SEM) below?
It's a "two-step" model in the sense that there are two causal linkages, one from orphanhood (Link 1) to poverty/maltreatment (Link 2), and one from these mediators to the ultimate outcome, depression (Link 3).
I want to include a moderator at Link 2, i.e., AgePoverty. (I haven't included the single "Age" variable in the diagram for clarity). I cannot include a covariance between AgePoverty and Poverty, because Poverty is a dependent variable, but the specification will not be correct if I don't account for their interrelationship.
Can someone please help me with appropriate references?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It would actually be more clear if you did add the age variable in the diagram.

In SEM moderator variable itself needs to be taken account in the path as seen in its Wikipedia reference.

To quantify the effect of a moderating variable in multiple regression analyses, regressing random variable $Y$ on $X$, an additional term is added to the model. This term is the interaction between $X$ and the proposed moderating variable.
Thus, for a response $Y$ and two variables $x_1$ and moderating variable $x_2$,:
$${\displaystyle Y=b_{0}+b_{1}x_{1}+b_{2}x_{2}+b_{3}(x_{1}\times x_{2})+\varepsilon \,}$$
In this case, the role of $x_2$ as a moderating variable is accomplished by evaluating $b_3$, the parameter estimate for the interaction term.

